# ¿Cómo recortar o redimensionar una imagen con HTML y CSS?

Tags: javascript, html5, pug

La funcionalidad que busco es que al momento de subir una imagen, el usuario pueda redimensionar, hacerle zoom y que la pueda guardar con esa escala, pero no he encontrado la forma de hacer eso.

La forma en el que lo tengo implementado es que se muestra la imagen una vez que está cargada, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y que al momento de hacer clic para hacer zoom, se pueda hacer más grande la imagen, terminando algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código de esa parte de la página, con su parte de JavaScript para mostrar la imagen cargada:

```js
$(document).on('click','.viewDesign',function(){
  if($(this).parent().find('input')[0].files[0]){
      $('#designPreview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL($(this).parent().find('input')[0].files[0]));
  }
  else if($(this).data('file')){
      $('#designPreview').attr('src', $(this).data('file'));
  }
 });
```

```html
.container
  img.design#designPreview(src="img/diseno/diseno.png")
  .escala
    p Escala
    .buttons
      i(type='button') -
      i(type='button') +
```

Comment: Necesitas más ayuda con CSS 3.

Comment: Podrías ser más específico, por favor?

Comment: Hola para usar componentes avanzados en las vistas puedes visitar este enlace. [https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form_advanced.html](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/form_advanced.html) Si bajas hay una funcionalidad muy buena para las imágenes.Saludos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creo que puedes hacerlo con este código, los comentarios son explicativos:

```
// Esperamos a que todo el HTML esté cargado antes de ejecutar Javascrip
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    // Input File
    const inputImage = document.querySelector('#image');
    // Nodo donde estará el editor
    const editor = document.querySelector('#editor');
    // El canvas donde se mostrará la previa
    const miCanvas = document.querySelector('#preview');
    // Contexto del canvas
    const contexto = miCanvas.getContext('2d');
    // Ruta de la imagen seleccionada
    let urlImage = undefined;
    // Evento disparado cuando se adjunte una imagen
    inputImage.addEventListener('change', abrirEditor, false);

    /**
    * Método que abre el editor con la imagen seleccionada
    */
    function abrirEditor(e) {
        // Obtiene la imagen
        urlImage = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);

        // Borra editor en caso que existiera una imagen previa
        editor.innerHTML = '';
        let cropprImg = document.createElement('img');
        cropprImg.setAttribute('id', 'croppr');
        editor.appendChild(cropprImg);

        // Limpia la previa en caso que existiera algún elemento previo
        contexto.clearRect(0, 0, miCanvas.width, miCanvas.height);

        // Envia la imagen al editor para su recorte
        document.querySelector('#croppr').setAttribute('src', urlImage);

        // Crea el editor
        new Croppr('#croppr', {
            aspectRatio: 1,
            startSize: [70, 70],
            onCropEnd: recortarImagen
        })
    }

    /**
    * Método que recorta la imagen con las coordenadas proporcionadas con croppr.js
    */
    function recortarImagen(data) {
        // Variables
        const inicioX = data.x;
        const inicioY = data.y;
        const nuevoAncho = data.width;
        const nuevaAltura = data.height;
        const zoom = 1;
        let imagenEn64 = '';
        // La imprimo
        miCanvas.width = nuevoAncho;
        miCanvas.height = nuevaAltura;
        // La declaro
        let miNuevaImagenTemp = new Image();
        // Cuando la imagen se carge se procederá al recorte
        miNuevaImagenTemp.onload = function() {
            // Se recorta
            contexto.drawImage(miNuevaImagenTemp, inicioX, inicioY, nuevoAncho * zoom, nuevaAltura * zoom, 0, 0, nuevoAncho, nuevaAltura);
            // Se transforma a base64
            imagenEn64 = miCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
            // Mostramos el código generado
            document.querySelector('#base64').textContent = imagenEn64;
            document.querySelector('#base64HTML').textContent = '<img src="' + imagenEn64.slice(0, 40) + '...">';

        }
        // Proporciona la imagen cruda, sin editarla por ahora
        miNuevaImagenTemp.src = urlImage;
    }
});
```

Cualquier información adicional, [acá esta la fuente](https://programadorwebvalencia.com/javascript-recortar-y-previsualizar-imagen/).

Éxitos!